# How to Convert Linq to Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq

```
var getr = (from d in _context.DR
                       join r in _context.R on d.RID equals r.RID
                       where HID == r.HID && cI >= d.DRD && cO < d.DRD
                       group d by new {d.RID, d.RGID} into g
                       select g);
```

How to convert Linq to lambda? This is what I got:

```
var getr = _context.DR.Join(_context.R, x => x.RID, y => y.RID, (x, y) => new { R= x, DR= y}).Where(z => z.DR.RID== y.RID);
```

Are there any pros and cons of using either one?

Comment: The second one is more consistent with other programming languages. The two are semantically equivalent. They are called "query" and "method" syntax, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In terms of performance :** there is no performance difference whatsoever between two.

Which one should use is mostly personal preference, but its important to bear in mind that there are situation where one will be better suited the other.

```
int[] ints = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

// using Query expression
var evensQuery = from i in ints where isEven(i) select i;
// using Lambda expression
var evensLambda = ints.Where(isEven);
```

There so many function that available with lambda ie. single(), First(), Take(), Skip()..

Although you can mix and match the two by calling the Lambda-only methods at the end of the query:

```
// mix and match query and Lambda syntax
//Example ver :1
var query = (from person in people
             join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner
             select new { OwnerName = person.Name, Pet = pet.Name }).Skip(1).Take(2);
```

or, for better readability :

```
//Example ver :2
var query = from person in people
            join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner
            select new { OwnerName = person.Name, Pet = pet.Name };

var result = query.Skip(1).Take(2);
```

Both example version return the same output without performance differences because of delayed(or Deferred ) execution, that means query is not executing at the point of declaration, but it will execute when try to iterate through the result variable.

BUT, if you don’t want delayed execution, or need to use one of the aggregate functions such as Average() or Sum(), for example, you should be aware of the possibility of the underlying sequence being modified between the assignments to query and result. In this case,I’d argue it’s best to use Lambda expressions to start with or add the Lambda-only methods to the query expression.

Comment: Thanks for the info! But could you please show me an example of using the functions join and group by in lambda?

Comment: Hi, I'm still stuck on the doing the group by into and select parts in my example. I did the group by part, however, I do not know how to assign it into a variable and select it in lambda